# Permutations in a Bruhat interval with a fixed point

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $[e,\sigma_0]$ be the Bruhat interval of the permutations $\sigma\leq \sigma_0$ for the (strong) Bruhat order. I am interested in the following set, for fixed $i,j$:
$$[e,\sigma_0]_i^j:=\{ \sigma \in [e,\sigma_0] \mid \sigma(i)=j\}.$$
The set $[e,\sigma_0]_i^j$ can be embedded ("flattened") in $S_{N-1}$ by removing $(i,j)$ and keeping the relative order of all other entries.

My question is: is there necessarily $\sigma_0'\in S_{N-1}$ such that $[e,\sigma_0]_i^j = [e, \sigma_0']$?

From computer experiments, it seems to be true if $\sigma_0$ avoids the pattern $3412$.
For example, $[e,3412]_2^2=\{e,1243,3214\} \xrightarrow{\text{flatten}} \{e, 132, 213\} \subset S_3$, which is not a Bruhat interval.

Is this result known? Does somebody have a reference for this?

Comment: Permutations that avoid 2143 are called "vexillary" and a lot is written about them, especially in the context of "Coxeter/Bruhat stuff." The permutations that avoid 3412 are the reverses of vexillary permutations.